# Save input data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, firebase

I want to store/push input data in [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/).

**Form HTML**

```
<form>
<input name="name" type="name" placeholder="Title" id="titleInput" />
<button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="submitPost()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Pushing input data to firebase**

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://eloquatest.firebaseio.com/');
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var post = snapshot.val();
});

function submitPost(e) {
  var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://eloquatest.firebaseio.com/');
  var name = $('#titleInput').val();
  myDataRef.push({name: name});
}
```

Above code works in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbaecklund/gddsego7/5/). In my case I can't put the https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js in the site header, so I figured to try it with Ajax.

**Form HTML as with jquery**

```
$('header').prepend ('<form><input name="name" type="name" id="titleInput"/>    
<button type="submit" onclick="submitPost()">Submit</button></form>');
```

**I'm not very familiar with Ajax and below transformed code do not work. Help?**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true,
  success: function () {
  var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://eloquatest.firebaseio.com/');
  myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var post = snapshot.val();
  displayUserPost(post.name);
});
}
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true,
  success: function submitPost(e) {
  var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://eloquatest.firebaseio.com/');
  var name = $('#titleInput').val();
  myDataRef.push({name: name});
  $('#postInput').val('');
  e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is add 3rd script to our DOM by javascript.
Add onload function to handle when 3rd script loaded and do your stuff.

You can add this script on your js file, on document ready is not a bad idea.

```
window.firebaseInit = function(){
     var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://eloquatest.firebaseio.com/');
     ......
     <Do whatever you want here!>
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js";
    js.onload = window.firebaseInit;
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'id-firebase'));
```

This script I learn from Facebook. You can using jQuery.getScript and put your init FireBase function on success params, document here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/